# An easy-to-use javascript library to draw a timeline on a web browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, timeline

Does anyone know what javascript library can I use to draw a timeline such as the one below ?[image]

Actually, I've found the [Timestack.js](http://isaaccambron.com/timestack/) library but the main issue is that I can't align boxes (i.e. I can't put every boxes at the same height, as below)...

[image]

Thanks for your help :).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Rather easy to code yourself no? The difference between 14:25 and 15:06 in (milli)seconds is 100%. Each box takes up x% of the interval. So the width of each box is just basic % calculations. Aligning them can be done any way you prefer: Flexbox, grid, list elements...

Comment: What should be great for me is to use Timestack.js to draw my timeline but with boxes alignment. However, such issue is an [open issue](https://github.com/icambron/timestack/issues/3) since March 2016...